# Django ORM compare tuples / lexicographic ordering

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, django, postgresql

As part of some custom cursor-based pagination code in Python Django, I would like to have the below filtering and ordering on a generic Queryset (where I don't know the table name up front)

```sql
WHERE (col_a, col_b) > (%s, %s)
ORDER BY col_a, col_b
```

How can this be expressed in terms of the Django ORM?

Note I would like the SQL to keep the tuple comparison and not have this based on `AND` clauses. In some previous tests, it seemed more likely that PostgreSQL would be more likely to use multi-column indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a way that works in Django pre 3.2, using `annotate` (which also unfortunately needs the slight hack of setting an `output_field`, even though the value isn't used).

```py
from django.db.models import F, Func, TextField

col_a_col_b = Func(F('col_a'), F('col_b'), function='ROW', output_type=TextField())
col_a_col_b_from = Func(col_a_value, col_b_value, function='ROW')

filtered_queryset = queryset \
    .annotate(col_a_col_b=col_a_col_b) \
    .filter(col_a_col_b__gt=col_a_col_b_from) \
    .order_by('col_a', 'col_b')
```

In Django 3.2+ you can apparently use `alias` instead of `annotate`

This works since what is referred to as a tuple, is actually shorthand for a [Row Constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS), i.e. `(col_a, col_b)` is the same thing as `ROW(col_a, col_b)`

The above is based on the information in [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29527)