# Django extra + where: how to escape identifiers

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, sql-injection

I have an `extra` filter in Django with a `where` clause, but the table name is dynamic.

```py
filtered_queryset = queryset.extra(
    where=[
        f'({table_name}.modified_on, {table_name}.id) > (%s, %s)',
    ],
    params=(after_ts, after_id),
)
```

How can I best avoid the f-string to make really sure it's not open to SQL injection?

I would like the SQL to have the tuple comparison, rather than multiple `>` and `>=` with `AND`. From previous testing, it seemed more likely to use multi-column indexes.

(This is part of some custom pagination code, where the cursor is essentially a tuple of a datetime and id)

Comment: per the docs, extra is deprecated and they want feedback on cases where it is needed: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#extra

Comment: Of course, you can always esape it yourself by having a list of valid table names and looking up the table name in that, but you likely don't want to do that

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you write it as a filter?

```
filtered_queryset = queryset.filter(
    Q(modified_on__gt=after_ts) |
    Q(Q(modified_on__gte=after_ts) & Q(id__gt=after_id))
)
```

PS: It's a bit unclear what your query is trying to do, I think it's this, but maybe you want to filter on something else.

Comment: I've added some more detail to the question about why I would like to avoid this

Comment: I don't know how to force a certain SQL usage by Django, so I am afraid I cannot help you further with this. :-(

Answer (score 1):

First, validate your `table_name` variable against a list of known table names.

Also, use double-quotes as identifier delimiters, which allows `table_name` to be an SQL reserved keyword, or contain spaces or punctuation. These are all legal in SQL, as long as you use identifier delimiters.

```
    f'("{table_name}".modified_on, "{table_name}".id) > (%s, %s)',
```

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

However, if your table name contains a literal `"` character, this could cause trouble, because the `"` symbol would be interpreted as the terminating identifer delimiter. So it's up to you to filter your `table_name`, replacing a literal `"` with `""`.

Answer (score 0):

As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69323794/1319998), `extra` can be avoided by using `annotate`, and the table name is taken from the Queryset's model internally, which avoids having to worry about escaping any identifiers:

```py
from django.db.models import F, Func, TextField

col_a_col_b = Func(F('col_a'), F('col_b'), function='ROW', output_type=TextField())
col_a_col_b_from = Func(col_a_value, col_b_value, function='ROW')

filtered_queryset = queryset
    .annotate(col_a_col_b=col_a_col_b)
    .filter(col_a_col_b__gt=col_a_col_b_from)
    .order_by('col_a', 'col_b')
```

(Apparently in Django 3.2+ `alias` can be used instead of `extra`, and the `output_field` hack avoided)